# How can I update the next cell's value in ngx-datatable based on the selection of value in a dropdown?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm trying to update another cell value, in the first cell I have a dropdown, and based on the selection of value in dropdown, I have to update the values of dropdown in next column.

How can I achieve this using ngx-datatable-columns?

This is the cell that contains the dropdown:

```
 <ngx-datatable-column name="status" prop="operationStatus" >
    <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" ngx-datatable-cell-template>

        <select class="status" (change)="changeStatus($event, rowIndex)">
          <option *ngFor="let e of selectableGerateStatus" [selected]="value == e.id">
               {{e.label}}
            </option>
        </select>

    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
```

This is the cell that needs to be updated:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="casette" prop="cassette1Bill">
    <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
      <span>Kassette 1</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <div>{{value}}</div>

    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
```

Comment: I have no idea, but am pretty sure you can know if $event contains it by checking it with dev tools

Comment: It's very unclear... You are using ag-grid, but for example, on the other hand you have shown ngx-datatable-column. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help u easily.

Comment: @Paritosh, I was a bit confused, sorry. I used ag-grid because being a beginner in the realm of angular I was under the impression that  I need ag-grid to achieve this.  Now I made an edit, and I dropped ag-grid. Please focus on ngx-datatable only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are already have the entire row's data at your disposal, since you are using `let-row` on your columns. Since you have assigned `row` to `let-row`, you can pass `row` (which is an object containing that row data) to your `(change)` event binding.

On your .html file, simply make the following changes on that column with that dropdown:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="status" prop="operationStatus" >
    <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" ngx-datatable-cell-template>

    <select class="status" (change)="changeStatus(row)">
      <option *ngFor="let e of selectableGerateStatus" [selected]="value == e.id">
               {{e.label}}
      </option>
    </select>

  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Basically, we have passed the row details `row` to `changeStatus()`

And on your component.ts, simply assign that value to the `cassette1Bill` column

```
changeStatus(row) {
  //console.log(row)
  row.cassette1Bill = '22';
}
```

This should work. That column should reflect the updated values from that selected dropdown value.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I need. +1 because it is clear and it came fast. Thanks.